# Maximum size of DynamoDB item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know what is the maximum size of Item payload that amazon dynamo DB supports? I am sure its buried in documentation somewhere.

My follow-up question is that when you upload large chunk of data if there is a connection drop (client or server), is there a way to resume the upload from where you left off?

Comment: What do you mean by "when you upload large chunk of data"? Do you mean if the Write operation did not complete? I would imagine that it either completes fully or does not store any data, but I have no reference for this.

Comment: Lets say i have the following {
  "key": "key",
  "value": "large string"
} . Lets say the total payload is about 1gb, in the middle of transfer if connection aborts , it could be client or server, can i resume the upload ?

Comment: FWIW the answers are 400KB and no.

Comment: Dynamodb-item-size-limit-error https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-errors/dynamodb-item-size-limit-error/

Answer (score 41):

The maximum size of a DynamoDB item is 400KB.

From the [Limits in DynamoDB documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html):

> The maximum item size in DynamoDB is **400 KB**, which includes both attribute name binary length (UTF-8 length) and attribute value lengths (again binary length). The attribute name counts towards the size limit.

Comment: Remember that 400K includes the corresponding item in the LSI as well. So if your table has an LSI, the limit for each item is actually less than 400K

Comment: @prayagupd We don't live in a world with unlimited resources unfortunately

Comment: Dynamodb item size limit error https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-errors/dynamodb-item-size-limit-error/

Answer (score 5):

This is what i could figure from documentation

- Unlimited attributes /item
- Unlimited item /table
- 400KB max /attribute
  *- 64KB max /item name* [Edited per documentation --an item name must be at least one character long, but not greater than 64 KB long.]

Large data needs to be stored in Amazon S3 with url pointing to the data ?

Comment: Aren't items made of attributes? How can max attribute size be more than item size?

Comment: Yes item is made of attributes, size of each attribute is limited to 400KB but overall you can have unlimited items

Comment: Item Size
The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB, which includes both attribute name binary length (UTF-8 length) and attribute value lengths (again binary length). The attribute name counts towards the size limit.

For example, consider an item with two attributes: one attribute named "shirt-color" with value "R" and another attribute named "shirt-size" with value "M". The total size of that item is 23 bytes.

Item Size for Tables with Local Secondary Indexes
For each local secondary index on a table, there is a 400 KB limit on the total of the following:

Comment: The size of an item's data in the table.

The size of the local secondary index entry corresponding to that item, including its key values and projected attributes.

Attributes
Attribute Name-Value Pairs Per Item
The cumulative size of attributes per item must fit within the maximum DynamoDB item size (400 KB).

Number of Values in List, Map, or Set
There is no limit on the number of values in a List, a Map, or a Set, as long as the item containing the values fits within the 400 KB item size limit.

Comment: Attribute Values
An attribute value cannot be an empty String or empty Set (String Set, Number Set, or Binary Set). However, empty Lists and Maps are allowed.

Nested Attribute Depth
DynamoDB supports nested attributes up to 32 levels deep.

Comment: I think it would be best to simply delete this answer given that the correct answer has already been provided, rather than to simply copy/paste the documentation into multiple comments,

Comment: jarmod, the answer was based on the documentation at that time. things might have changed now. you can't say simply this is bad, which statement is wrong here?. I will be happy to update the answer if you indicate which statement is wrong.

Comment: Here are the sections from the documentation cited in the comments: [Item Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-items), [Attribute Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-attributes)

Comment: The answer should be updated to say 400KB max /item rather than /attribute. Per the documentation cited in the comments, "The _cumulative_ size of attributes per item must fit within the maximum DynamoDB item size (400 KB)."

Comment: @fenix.shadow updated the answer as per your request

Comment: @webjockey could you simply add more attributes? if an attribute is named "column" and it's string limit is 400kb and you reach that limit couldn't you create a new attribute "column2" and have another 400kb to work with? then later you simply check if "column2" exists and combine the value with "column"? OR is an "item" like a table row. And the max string content of the row is all it's attributes combined to 400kb? If the limit is 400kb per row then your suggestion to store large data in Amazon S3 with url pointing to the data makes sense.