# Why do databases limit row/value size?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-dynamodb, b-tree

I have been reading about databases and looks like most of the databases impose a limit on the size of a value (key-value store/document-based*) or the size of a row (relational database*). Although I understand the limitations on the size of the key/primary-key, it helps to increase the branching factor of BTree such that each BTree node can be fetched within one read of a block on file-system. For values, I assume that the keys store just a pointer to the file containing the value which allows values to be arbitrarily large. Is it that the pointer thing is true only for text/blob kind of data and the rest of the values are stored in the Btree node? But storing values with the Btree node itself helps optimize just one IO (to go and start reading the file pointed by the pointer), the size restriction seems to be a lot for the trade-off.

References:
Limit on mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html
Limit on dynamodb: [Maximum size of DynamoDB item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181346/maximum-size-of-dynamodb-item)

Answer (score 1):

Cursor based result set traversal is a thing I suggest, DB clients won't be fetching half a row at any time, so if there's no limit on the row size, the client side lib would have to be ready facing arbitrary lengthy binary streams, which obviously make it much harder to design an efficient while still correct wire protocol for C/S communication.

But I don't thing that's the whole story, many other concerns can count as well.